# How to avoid the extra iterations when using Python coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, coroutine, yield

Here is a co-routine in Python 3.9

```py
def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start


@coroutine
def grep(pattern):
    while True:
        line = yield "I have to yield something here?"
        if pattern in line:
            # do something fancy to the line
            yield line
        else:
            raise ValueError("err")
```

Since the `line = yield` is receiving and sending data, I need to do extra `next` calls to make it work:

```py
gg = grep("thing")

item = gg.send("That thing!")
print(item)
next(gg)

item = gg.send("That thing also!")
print(item)
next(gg)

item = gg.send("And what about here this thing.")
print(item)
next(gg)

item = gg.send("Not this.")
print(item)
next(gg)
```

which prints:

```
That thing!
That thing also!
And what about here this thing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erasmose/Workspace/clustr/cmapper/temp.py", line 33, in <module>
    item = gg.send("Not this.")
  File "/home/erasmose/Workspace/clustr/cmapper/temp.py", line 16, in grep
    raise ValueError("err")
ValueError: err
```

If I remove the "next" calls:

```py
gg = grep("thing")

item = gg.send("That thing!")
print(item)

item = gg.send("That thing also!")
print(item)

item = gg.send("And what about here this thing.")
print(item)

item = gg.send("Not this.")
print(item)
```

The output is:

```
That thing!
I have to yield something here?
And what about here this thing.
I have to yield something here?
```

Is there any way to avoid those extra "next" calls?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to combine the two `yield` statements, so that the coroutine sends and receives in the same `yield`

You'll still need an extra yield to start the process off, though.

Something like this:

```
@coroutine
def grep(pattern):
    line = yield "I have to yield something here?"  # receive the first one
    while True:
        if pattern in line:
            line = yield line  # send and receive in one yield statement
        else:
            raise ValueError("err")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sabik. I need to do some processing on the `line` before yielding it. This was a simplified code. How can I get the `line`, process it and yield it in the same line of code?

Comment: The `line = yield line` statement yields the previous line, then receives the next one; you can do all the processing before that statement (within the loop)

Comment: If you prefer, you can use `next_line = yield line` instead